# Configuring Passenger on Openshift

Tags: phusion-passenger, openshift-online-2

When running a Ruby application on Openshift, is it possible to specify custom Passenger configuration options?

In particular, I'd like to override the value of `PassengerMaxPoolSize` that's getting set in `$OPENSHIFT_RUBY_DIR/etc/conf.d/performance.conf`. Unfortunately all files in that directory require root access to modify.

Is it possible to override `PassengerMaxPoolSize` without root access?

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to edit that value in the supported OpenShift Ruby Cartridge (see product documentation for what is changable http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_cartridge_guide.html#ruby). You can however create a custom ruby cartridge with your preferred settings and run that on OpenShift.

Comment: Ah that makes sense — thanks for the reply, Nick. As an alternative, I found these two forum posts that suggest using the `.htaccess` file to add additional Passenger config options: https://forums.openshift.com/changing-passengerpoolidletime, https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-not-show-passenger-page-in-case-of-exceptions-in-a-rubysinatra-app. I know those are pretty old, but is this still a supported option? As an experiment, I tried adding `PassengerMinInstances` to an `.htaccess` in my root directory but that didn't seem to do anything :(

Comment: I'll have to test to see if its still works but really quickly, did you put it in the root of your repo or of your gear? If it was in the root of your gear, try putting it in the root of your repo.

Comment: I added it to the root of my repo, in the same directory as my `config.ru` file. Currently my `.htaccess` file has a single line `PassengerMinInstances 2`. But `passenger-status` still shows me dropping down to a single process periodically, which suggests that something's not working =/